12 people sitting in a circular table and 3 are friends
I'm working on this question: Suppose 12 guests are invited to a party that will take place at a circular table (i.e. seat 1 is next to seat 12). A group of 3 friends attend and are randomly assigned one of the 12 seats. What is the probability that at least 2 of the 3 friends will sit next to each other?
I'm trying to understand the answer from here, pasted below:

There are 11! factorial arrangements of the people, since they wrap
around in a circle. The only way the "2 friends sit next to each
other" doesn't happens is if all of the friends are separated by at
least one person.
Arrange all the 9 non-friends. 9! ways for that.
Place first friend anywhere.
To find the ways to rule out:
Place second friend in any of the eight gaps between the original
non-friends.
Third friend can go in any of the 7 gaps not next to one of the first
two friends.
9!(8)(7) ways we want to rule out.

Can someone please explain to me why "Arrange all the 9 non-friends. 9! ways for that." is correct? Shouldn't it be $(9-1)! = 8!$ for that? We subtract 1 from 12 and found $11!$ seating arrangements. Why are not we doing the same to $9!$?
I know there are other answers floating on the forum, but I'm trying to understand the logic behind this one. Thank you.

Once you place one of the friends at the table, that person becomes your reference point.  Relative to that person, you can place the nine non-friends around the table in $9!$ ways as you proceed clockwise around the table since there are nine choices for the non-friend who sits to the immediate left of the friend who is initially seated, $8$ ways to choose the non-friend who sits to. the immediate left of that person, and so forth.

W.l.o.g. suppose the first friend is at seat $1$. There are 11 ways to sit the second friend:

in two of these cases (seat $12$ and $2$) we already have two friends next to each other;

in two of these cases (seat $10$ and $3$) there are 3 possible locations (out of 10) for the third one, to ensure the condition (e.g. if they are at seats $1$ and $3$, the third one may sit at one of $11,2,4$);

in the remaining 7 cases there are 4 possible locations for the third one, to ensure the condition (on either side of the first or the second).


Hence, the desired probability is
$$
\frac2{11}+\frac2{11}\times \frac{3}{10}+\frac7{11}\times \frac{4}{10}=\frac{27}{55}.
$$

Since probability has been asked for, there is a much simpler way to get the answer without running around in circles :)

The $9$ non-friends seated in a circle create $9$ "bins" between them, so by stars and bars, total ways to seat the friends $=\binom{3+9-1}{3} = \binom{11}3$
Ways to seat the friends all apart $= \binom93$

$$Thus\;\; Pr = 1 -\dfrac{\binom93}{\binom{11}3} = \frac{27}{55}$$

By placing the first friend we essentially break the circle into two parts - to the left of the first friend and to the right. Thus, a circular arrangement principle will no longer apply. Let's say we have three people. There are $(3-1)!=2$ ways to sit them in a circle. But if we fix a sit for one person, there are still $2$ ways to sit the other two people.
